# What to do about InternalError

Tags: google-bigquery

Every now and then I start getting "Unexpected. Please try again." for ANY query i try. It usually gets better a bit later but the rate at which it appears is very worrying.

What can I do when this happens?

here are some job ids:

```
job_648552a52f3046c5b2df9300a31d4693
job_4af4184725974c3fb38e0ded96b776c9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get this response, please let us know because it indicates a bug in BigQuery.

Looking at the jobs in question, this is a race condition where we mark the import complete before it has completely replicated to all datacenters, and the query hits a different datacenter. I've filed a bug and we're working on a fix.

Comment: thanks. this seems to match my findings very well. i will mark the question as answered.